# call angular function from plain javascript in head

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a poorly formed question, but I don't yet have the knowledge to articulate it. I have also inherited a messy project so I can't really give much example code. I have defined a function `$scope.$back` in a controller `testCtrl` which exists in the `angular.module('messyApp')`. This is on a separate js page `main.js`.

I want to call this function from a plain javascript script in the header when I trigger an `onkeydown` event after the angular stuff has loaded. I have an idea I need to call angulars `$apply` function after, but I cannot figure out how to access any of these functions, as I get the error they are undefined.

I am using `$routeProvider` to asign the `testCtrl` controller. Here's some code that may be of some use;

```
<html>
<head>

   ...loads of scripts and stuff...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function keyFunc(e) {

            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    console.log('left');
                    break;
                case 38:
                    console.log('up');
                    break;
                case 39:
                    console.log('right');
                    break;
                case 40:
                    console.log('down');
                    break;
            }

            $rootScope.$next(); // angular function im trying to trigger
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="messyApp" onkeydown="keyFunc(event)">

    ...tons more scripts...

</body>
</html>
```

The angular function `$back()` triggers on a hyperlink elsewhere in the page using

```
<a ng-click="$back()"><div class="icon" id="backicon"><img src="back.png" /></div></a>
```

so if it really comes to it, I could accept an *even more* hacky solution of the js triggering this hyperlink instead (which would trigger the angular, I assume).

Comment: `If you do angular.element('body').scope()` in keyFunc you will get hold of `rootScope`

Comment: Ok, I have access to the $rootScope thanks, but I still can't figure out how to call the function?

Comment: First the function should be defined on scope. Secondly you need to know which html element is the scope attached to. Then just reference that html element using angular.element syntax and get its scope and call the function. Where is $next defined. In there is corresponding ng-controller defined, use that element.

Comment: Thankyou. I defined the function in $rootScope instead of scope and called an $apply() after. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to access a function defined on `$rootScope`, you have to reference it properly in your html with `$root.`. For example: `<a ng-click="$root.$back()"></a>`

There are a number of other issues however. I would really recommend using ui-router and state-based navigation as it will make your life much easier. Further, avoid using $rootScope wherever possible. For binding to keys, it's best practice to use angular directives. For example, if you wanted to bind to the enter key, your code would look something like this inside of the directive's link function:

```
element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
      if(event.which === 13) {
         doSomething();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to add something like this:

```
<body ng-app="messyApp" ng-keydown="$next()">
```

Comment: I tried something like this originally but the angular stuff doesn't seem to trigger anything, which is why I turned to plain javascript to listen for the keypresses.